# Can the overhead of implementing ContentProvider for an internally used Database be avoided?

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-database, android-loader

The [Android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) states :

> You don't need to develop your own provider if you don't intend to
>   share your data with other applications.

So It is understood that if i have a SQLite DB used entirely locally in the app then a ContentProvider should not be needed (having a lot of boilerplate code writing avoided), but I didnt get whats the "Android" way to query this DB on the background? (with as less overhead of re-inventing the wheel as possible)

It may seem that this task is what [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#summary) are for, as sateted in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) :

> loaders make it easy to asynchronously load data in an activity or
>   fragment.

but there is no subclass of `Loader` that can carry this task out, The closest subclass - [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) is desgined to be coupled with a `ContentResolver`. So, am i missing something? Is there a third party implementation of Loader that does that or is there another approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> whats the "Android" way to query this DB on the background?

Whatever you want. Use an `AsyncTask`. Use a plain `Thread`. Use an `IntentService`. See if your preferred ORM has an asynchronous option, or hooks into RxJava/RxAndroid, or something.

IOW, there is no single "Android" way.

> It may seem that this task is what Loaders are for, as sateted in the docs :

A `Loader` is only relevant in cases where you want the UI layer to be working with the database fairly directly. You can only use a `Loader` with an `Activity` or `Fragment`.

> am i missing something?

You are welcome to create your own subclass of `AsyncTaskLoader` that works with SQLite directly, perhaps using the source code to `CursorLoader` as a source of inspiration.

> Is there a third party implementation of Loader that does that

I had one, once. However, [I discontinued it](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/03/31/cwac-loaderex-failed-abstractions.html).

Comment: So what do you use now when you need to query the database in the background and dont want the hassle to deal with activity lifecycle and synchronization,ever since you have come to a conclusion that a Loader subclass isnt right for that task?

Comment: @OfekRon: That varies widely by app. Also, for an individual project, if you want to create your own `DatabaseLoader` that simply does not honor the full `Loader` contract, you are welcome to do so. I discontinued my library because I could not honor the full contract and I did not want to mislead users of the library. But, besides loaders, you can use threads and retained fragments, or threads and `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, or POJO database managers, etc. It really depends on the nature of the app, your overall UI architecture, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A `Loader` is a mechanism that hooks in to the Activity lifecycle that can be used to asynchronously load any kind of data whether ContentProvider, network, or you just need to crunch a bunch of numbers.

At the base there is a Loader called the [AsyncTaskLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) which a `CursorLoader` actually inherits from.  This can be used to provide the base level functionality of a Loader.  All you have to do is implement a 
data model that you need to load, then implement the `AsyncTaskLoader#loadInBackground()` method to get it.  In this case, you would query the database then return the results in a form of your choosing.  Maybe in this case you don't want to return a `Cursor` but you want to create Pojo's that represent a row in your Cursor for example.

As a quick implementation, you may be able to take [CursorLoader's source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/CursorLoader.java) and have it query from your database instead of using a `ContentResolver`.

Answer (score 0):

No need for ContentProvider if you don't

- share data with other processes (applications);
- build App Widget;
- integrate your own search suggestions with the Android Quick Search Box;

... and you do not want a fancy syncing and querying data with auto-UI update.

Actually, you can try to wrap read/write DB operation in `AsyncTaskLoader` (AsyncTask that respects activity lifecycle). Also you will have to implement your own observers to update views (one more option to use [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)).